# Get Phone number from an array match with label React native

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, react-native

I have an array like this:

```
[{"label": "home", "number": "555-522-8243"}]
[{"label": "home", "number": "555-478-7672"}, {"label": "mobile", "number": "(408) 555-5270"}, {"label": "home fax", "number": "(408) 555-3514"}]
[{"label": "home", "number": "555-610-6679"}]
[{"label": "work", "number": "(555) 766-4823"}, {"label": "other", "number": "(707) 555-1854"}]
[{"label": "mobile", "number": "888-555-5512"}, {"label": "home", "number": "888-555-1212"}]
[{"label": "mobile", "number": "(555) 564-8583"}, {"label": "main", "number": "(415) 555-3695"}]
```

And here is my `function`

```
function getPhoneNumber(item) {
    console.log(item);
    return item.map(a => {
        switch(a.label) {
            case 'mobile':
                return a.number;
                break;
            case 'main':
                return a.number;
                break;
        }
    });
}
```

Then I call that `funtionc` like so: `getPhoneNumber(data.phoneNumbers)`, but if one contact have both `mobile` & `main` label, it show me 2 phone number. I just want show one phone number. How I fix that.

Here is my sreen:

[image]

Thank you. :))

Comment: If only one will be shown, what is the preferred number type if both are there? `main` or `mobile`?

Comment: Maybe a .map() is not what you need

Comment: What would be return value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need something like this.

in `phoneNumberIncludingKeys` put a list of keys from which you want to get and show the number

```
const phoneNumberIncludingKeys = ['mobile', 'main', 'work']

function getPhoneNumber(list) {
    const obj = list.find(item => phoneNumberIncludingKeys.includes(item.label))
    if (obj) {
        return obj.number
    }
    return null
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you aren't bothered about whether it is a home, mobile, or other number the following function will probably be suitable.

```
var someArrayItem = [{"label": "home", "number": "555-478-7672"}, {"label": "mobile", "number": "(408) 555-5270"}, {"label": "home fax", "number": "(408) 555-3514"}]

function getPhoneNumber(item) {
    return item[0].number;
}
console.log(getPhoneNumber(someArrayItem));
```

or alternatively with a bigger array with multiple elements:

```
var someArray=[[{label:"home",number:"555-522-8243"}],[{label:"home",number:"555-478-7672"},{label:"mobile",number:"(408) 555-5270"},{label:"home fax",number:"(408) 555-3514"}],[{label:"home",number:"555-610-6679"}],[{label:"work",number:"(555) 766-4823"},{label:"other",number:"(707) 555-1854"}],[{label:"mobile",number:"888-555-5512"},{label:"home",number:"888-555-1212"}],[{label:"mobile",number:"(555) 564-8583"},{label:"main",number:"(415) 555-3695"}]];

function getPhoneNumber_2(item) {
    return item.map(a => {
        if (a[0].label) {
            return a[0].number;
        }
    });
}
    
console.log(getPhoneNumber_2(someArray));
```

However if you are concerned with a specified label, you could do it like this. Effectively loop through the data until the specified label is found and return said number associated with the label.

```
var someArray = [{"label": "home", "number": "555-478-7672"}, {"label": "mobile", "number": "(408) 555-5270"}, {"label": "home fax", "number": "(408) 555-3514"}]

function getPhoneNumber_3(item, label) {
    for (var key in item) {
        if (item[key].label === label) {
            return item[key].number;
        }
    }
}

console.log(getPhoneNumber_3(someArray, "mobile"));
```

and again, with a bigger array, where the switch case returns the number associated with the label, if it does not exist then it simply reverts to whatever is available.

```
var someArray=[[{label:"home",number:"555-522-8243"}],[{label:"home",number:"555-478-7672"},{label:"mobile",number:"(408) 555-5270"},{label:"home fax",number:"(408) 555-3514"}],[{label:"home",number:"555-610-6679"}],[{label:"work",number:"(555) 766-4823"},{label:"other",number:"(707) 555-1854"}],[{label:"mobile",number:"888-555-5512"},{label:"home",number:"888-555-1212"}],[{label:"mobile",number:"(555) 564-8583"},{label:"main",number:"(415) 555-3695"}]];


function getPhoneNumber_4(item) {
    return item.map(a => {
        for (var index in a) {
            switch(a[index].label) {
                case 'mobile':
                    return a[index].number;
                    break;
                case 'main':
                    return a[index].number;
                    break;      
            }
           }
           return a[index].number;
        });
}

console.log(getPhoneNumber_4(someArray));
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `map()` you can `filter()` the inputs and use the first one from the list:

```js
let arr = [[{"label":"home","number":"555-522-8243"}],[{"label":"home","number":"555-478-7672"},{"label":"mobile","number":"(408) 555-5270"},{"label":"home fax","number":"(408) 555-3514"}],[{"label":"home","number":"555-610-6679"}],[{"label":"work","number":"(555) 766-4823"},{"label":"other","number":"(707) 555-1854"}],[{"label":"mobile","number":"888-555-5512"},{"label":"home","number":"888-555-1212"}],[{"label":"mobile","number":"(555) 564-8583"},{"label":"main","number":"(415) 555-3695"}]];

function getPhoneNumber(item) {
    return item.filter(a => a.label === 'mobile' || a.label === 'main')[0].number;
}

console.log(getPhoneNumber(arr[1]));
console.log(getPhoneNumber(arr[4]));
console.log(getPhoneNumber(arr[5]));
```